# TFS 2013 upgrade (error TF400534)

Tags: tfs

We are trying to upgrade our TFS2012 to TFS 2013, however we receive the error-message:

**Error : TF400534 : Package (updatetfs) caching failed with the following status : 0x80070005**

We have administrative rights, enough disk space and have tried both with web-installer and ISO-file. We believe that we meet all the requirements to do the upgrade, however we receive the above mentioned error and sees the following errors in the log:

> [0EA0:1134][2013-10-22T11:07:48]e000: Error 0x80020005: Failed to get value as numeric for variable: TFS_SetupStartTime
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed attempt to copy payload from: 'F:\packages\UpdateTfs\updatetfs.exe' to: C:\Users\FITADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{0bd548db-1305-4220-8d53-e7d4274e2ab1}\updatetfs.
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]i000: [Info] OnCacheAcquireComplete: wzPackageOrContainerId: updatetfs, wzPayloadId: updatetfs, hrStatus: 0x80070005, nRecommendation : 0
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]e000: Error 0x80070005: Failed to acquire payload from: 'F:\packages\UpdateTfs\updatetfs.exe' to working path: 'C:\Users\FITADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{0bd548db-1305-4220-8d53-e7d4274e2ab1}\updatetfs'
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]e313: Failed to acquire payload: updatetfs to working path: C:\Users\FITADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{0bd548db-1305-4220-8d53-e7d4274e2ab1}\updatetfs, error: 0x80070005.
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]i000: [Info] OnCachePackageComplete: wzPackageId: updatetfs, hrStatus: 0x80070005, nRecommendation : 5
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]i000: [Info] State Change: CachingPackage => CachingPackageComplete
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]e000: [Error] TF400534 : Package (updatetfs) caching failed with the following status : 0x80070005.  HRESULT : 0x80070005
>
> [0EA0:1EB8][2013-10-22T11:08:46]e000: [Error] Error Lookup For 0x80070005 returned: Access is denied.

Does anybody know how we can resolve this problem?

Comment: You are probably best contacting someone from Microsoft via the MSDN forums.

Comment: That looks like a "contact your service rep" kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact error.  Make sure you install SQL Server 2012 sp1 first, before you begin the TFS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the installer cannot copy all of the necessary setup files to the local C:\ drive

```
(Failed attempt to copy payload from: 'F:\packages\UpdateTfs\updatetfs.exe' to: C:\Users\FITADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\...etc. etc.
```

Reasons that it fails to copy include:

- Not enough free space on the C:\ drive
- No permission to copy to that folder location
- Installer media is corrupted

I read where you say you have enough free disk space, but I would double check that and make sure your C:\ drive has at least 5 GB of free space.

Good luck!